# Is C++ COM interface for imported "RegExp.tlb" implicitly sharing memory between processes?

Tags: c++, regex, com, interprocess

Good time. Sorry if my question is strange, but I'm new in things I've faced.

My case is in following, I'm using VB RegExp in C++ through COM as following:

```
#import "RegExp.tlb" no_namespace
...
void DoSomething() {
    ...
    static IRegExpPtr regExp( __uuidof(RegExp) );    
    regExp->Pattern = A2BSTR(m_szStrReg); // read on dll load from the file     
    if ( regExp->Test(someString) ) {
        IMatchCollectionPtr matches = regExp->Execute(someString);
        // my staff here
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

My questions are:

1. Am I doing everything right? (p.s. I know about CoInit and CoUninit but the question is not about them).
2. **Is `regExp` process safe?** The reason I ask this is cause I have several instances of my class with `DoSomething()` calling it for many times. And I have CRASH in regExp internals. Caused by heap corruption/invalid memory access randomly in different calls of regExp methods with different args.

I've checked the regExp pointer value, regExp->Pattern.GetAddress() and so on. And they are different in different processes. But when I've added named Mutex and wrapped `DoSomething()` with it adding interprocess synchronization - the CRASH DISSAPPEARED. That's why I am asking if regExp has something implicitly shared between processes?

Comment: smells like you are multi-threaded and have several threads using single instance of regExp

Comment: There's also seems to be a leak here: `regExp->Pattern = A2BSTR(m_szStrReg)`, assuming `Pattern` is of `_bstr_t` type.
Also, did you really mean to make `static IRegExpPtr regExp` static?

Comment: @pm100 No there is only one thread in several same processes.

Comment: @Noseratio as I know _com_ptr_t and _bstr_t are smart pointers: A _bstr_t object encapsulates the BSTR data type. The class manages resource allocation and deallocation through function calls to SysAllocString and SysFreeString and other BSTR APIs when appropriate. The _bstr_t class uses reference counting to avoid excessive overhead. So where should I look for the leak? And yes I really mean to make regExp static :)

Comment: @Mihail, `_bstr_t` indeed makes a copy of the passed string with `SysAllocString`. Yet `A2BSTR` also uses `SysAllocString` (have a look at atlconv.h), that's where this line of code leaks. Perhaps, you wanted `RegExp->Pattern = A2W(m_szStrReg)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is dealing with COM interface pointer living in current apartment. You are aware about COM initialization already, so current apartment means current thread if you are in STA in particular. You are guaranteed that methods of the interface pointer are callable but the back end of this interface pointer might vary: it can be implementation directly, or it can be a helper object (proxy) which transfers the call into the apartment where the actual object resides. The latter in particular might be in another process.

This is all thread safe and "process safe". The parameters are taken with the call to the actual object and then transferred back. Caller don't have to care whether it's dealing with real object or a proxy, and the callee too does not need to know whether it's called by actual caller or a helper stub.

Having said that, the code snippet above is good. The crash you were having has to have another cause.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Do I understand correctly that it is possible that two my processes can simultaneously transfer the call into the actual regex object resided somewhere in one apartment?

Comment: Yes this is possible, but it depends on how server is implemented. You are only showing client side code which is fine. On server, it can be STA or MTA object, MTA object might be thread safe or unsafe, it might be singleton at all etc. This is what is likely to be causing your issues. Poorly written COM server might be easily giving such troubles.